# Kinect Freezing After a Minute and a Half

Tags: kinect

I've been messing around with programming the old Kinect for a while, and something I've noticed is that whenever I start a program that uses the Kinect sensor, the Kinect will stop sending inputs after 1:30 minutes, no matter what program it is. For example, my game that I made will still have enemies moving around, but the player's rendered skeleton from the Kinect just freezes. I can't find anything about this anywhere online, so is it just mine? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug somewhere between the Microsoft SDK and using a Kinect for XBOX on Windows (didn't try the Kinect for Windows).

The Kinect stream freezes after 1 minute 28 seconds. In the Unity editor, you'll also notice once you reach this freeze, you need to quit and restart Unity to be able to play again. If not, you'll get messages like "Device not genuine", etc.

The only way to solve it that I found is to re-initialize whatever Kinect Manager you are using. For instance, Destroy()ing the gameObject holding the manager and re-Instantiate()ting it.

This will effectively halt your Kinect stream (and any gesture/joint reading) for about 4 seconds and then it will work again, so this is something the user will definitely notice.

Now, this may not work for most games, but if you're working on a casual game and you can keep it under 1:28 or you're able to show the user some sort of screen while you restart the Kinect manager every 1:20, you'll be safe.

If you never exceed the 1:28, you'll be able to stop and play in the Unity editor as many times as you want, and keep it running as many times as you want.

Now, this may not be an actual "answer", but may work for someone.

Let me know if you need any help to make this work. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the Kinect with built in programs in this link.[programs to check](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart) and see if it works smoothly. If not may be something wrong with your program.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue. At first I thought it was something related to Unity3d. But I tested with other programas and it's still happening.

Talking to the guy who developed the plugin he said: " two users complained that Kinect tracking stops after a while"
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/7747

Also, I sent him an email and he told me that more and more people are getting this issue.

Comment: This isn't an answer, and should be left as a comment on the question.

Comment: I can't comment. Because I'm new on stackoverflow. I must have 50 reputation to comment. I was trying to help.